# How to check validity of a user's subscription on Android with a SOAP web service?

Tags: android, rest, soap, google-api, in-app-billing

I know the best way to securely check this is using the Google Play Developer API and storing data on my own server.

However, the problem is that I have a SOAP web service, and the Google Play API is REST-based.  Since these can't interact with one another, I'm at a loss for what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your app needs to call the REST-based service, then you can just call it and ensure any payload sent/received is in JSON format. If your app needs to call your SOAP based service, then just call it, ensuring that the payload is SOAP formatted. If you have to call the REST service from your service, then you just call it with a JSON formatted payload. So if your service needs to call the REST service after your app has called your service, then you need to translate the payload sent from your app so that you can then call the REST service and when your service gets a response, you'll need to translate it back to SOAP format. It all depends on what component is calling what service.